# Forward a received email to a php script (sendmail)

Tags: php, sendmail, forward

I have created a system user `userA`.

In `/home/userA/` I have put a file `.forward` and a php script `script.php`

In the `.forward` I have put `/home/userA/script.php`

In the `script.php` I have put

```
#!usr/bin/php -q
<?php
mail('userB@myDomain.com','something','something else');
?>
```

The email in the script is correct and the server works. (my point is not to send an email but get some confirmation that the script was executed)

When I send a mail to my `userA@myDomain.com` the mail cannot be sent and I get a mailer-demon error:

```
    ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
/home/userA/script.php
   (reason: Can't create output)
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, two things or maybe three to make this work.

This solution work with sendmail.

first:

```
chmod 777 /home/userA/script.php
```

second: add a simlink in `/etc/smrsh` to the `script.php` file

```
ln -s /home/userA/script.php script.php
```

Third: add a simlink always in `/etc/smrsh` to the php bin itself! Don't ask why...

```
ln -s /usr/bin/php php
```

Fourth: in the `.forward` file that you created in `/home/userA/`

write only one line and start it with a `|` then `php` then filePath

ex `|php /home/userA/script.php`

In the `script.php` file, before the `<?php bla... ?>` add `#!/usr/bin/php -q` (I'm not sure if it's necessary but it works so...)

In this example php is located in `/usr/bin/php` You can do a `$ which php` to find where your php binary is located.

In the `script.php` if you want to access the mail that you forwarded you can by doing this

```
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
```

In some version of sendmail you must configure it yourself so that it use smrsh instead of sh (secured shell vs classic shell). You'll have to add smrsh in the `sendmail.mc`. Some infos here: [configure sendmail to use smrsh](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1473)

Now you can send an email to `userA@myDomain.com` and your email will be passed to a php script. Awesome right!?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call a php script and execute it you need a command like:
php /home/userA/script.php
It's more common than the #!usr/bin/php -q approach (and I'm sure it works)

Also, I don't think you can forward an email to a command with the .forward method.

What you can do is receiving the mail into userA mailbox, then use a daemon (php or bash script) to execute the script that will check the inbox for new mail.
Alternatively, if you only want to forward to another email adress, just put the adress in the .forward and it'll work.

Comment: You can forward a mail to a shell, php, perl or whatever script you want. I just did it.